# Is there another way of saying, "broken in?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that could replace the expression, **broken-in** as in "broken-in baseball gloves or a new pair of leather boots," meaning they are ready for comfortable use. Is there a simpler, shorter word that would convey the same message?

Comment: "old baseball gloves" is the only thing that comes to mind as 'simpler' but that is at the expense of exactness. It depends what you mean by 'simpler'!

Comment: For a vehicle or most machinery with an engine, it would be run-in.

Answer (score 27):

**Worn-in**, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worn-in):

> (of clothing) More comfortable as a result of having been worn often or for an extended period.

From the phrasal verb **to wear in**, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wear-in):

> if you wear in something such as a pair of shoes, you wear them until they fit your feet better and are more comfortable

#### Real-world examples

In reply to Mitch's comment, I have searched for real-world examples of this use as an adjective, I have found some on the Outdoors SE:

> But with **well worn-in boots** I always tend to get more blisters if I wear only one pair. [source](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1013/8227)
>
> Make sure you have **proper hiking boots**, which fit you well, and which **are well worn in**. [source](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/13434/8227)

Attribution:

[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worn-in) "Worn-in." Servent - Wiktionary. Accessed May 10, 2018. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worn-in.

[2](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wear-in) "Wear in (phrasal Verb) Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary." Grassroots (adjective) American English Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary. Accessed May 10, 2018. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wear-in.

[3](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1013/8227) Aim Kai. "Is It Better to Wear One Pair or Two Pairs of Socks While Hiking?" The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange. Accessed May 11, 2018. https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1013/8227.

[4](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/13434/8227) Fgysin. "How to Get Prepared for Fjällräven Classic Hiking Tour?" The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange. Accessed May 11, 2018. https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/13434/8227.

Comment: Can you use it as an adjective, as the OP has it? Are there any sentences like that in the wild?

Comment: Alternatively, **well-worn** works too

Comment: @Mitch it's hard to find using Google, but I found [Endaget used it in reference to a backpack](https://www.engadget.com/2011/11/30/irl-thule-crossover-backpack-technocel-battery-boost-and-upgra/): _"I'm still in the honeymoon period, but as I near the two-month mark the Crossover feels **worn-in**, with no signs of wearing through. "_

Comment: @mowwwalker feel free to add that as a separate answer (preferably with dictionary / real-world examples).

Comment: Plus, the wonderful orthogonality of  "worn, worn-in, worn-out"

Answer (score 17):

Seasoned.
Implying fully ready to use (consume) and having passed enough time to be found useful and satisfactory.

Comment: +1 - is a nice, broadly-applicable word (can be used for soldiers, food, tools, etc.). Would watch out for specific meanings with regards to wood and cast iron cookware, but I wouldn't expect that to be a problem.

Comment: I dunno, if someone told me their boots were "seasoned" I'd wonder what on earth they were doing putting salt and pepper on footwear...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If someone told me their footwear was ‘seasoned’, I’d suggest a long foot bath and perhaps a visit to a podiatrist.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's interesting that you mention _'a long foot bath'_, turns out that that's actually a way to break in boots, as evidenced by [this answer on the Outdoors SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/241/8227).

Answer (score 6):

I’d suggest **well-worn**.

[The OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/227725?redirectedFrom=Well+worn#eid) defines it as:

> **well-worn**
>
> Much worn or used; showing the signs of extensive use or wear.

Comment: This is a much later stage. Something that's just broken in is at its peak and may look perfect, but something that's well worn is well on its way to being worn out and looks it.

Comment: @ChrisH I’d argue that “well-worn” is a subset of broken in. For example “I don’t know if I want something so...broken in...” While for some things “broke in” is when it’s at its peak, for other broken in is already well-worn.

Answer (score 3):

The OP’s question mentions *ready for comfortable use* and *breaking in*. I think these are two different requirements. This answer is for the first one.

*These leathers boots have been **softened**.*

There are many articles online using this terminology for leather, e.g.

> **How to Soften Leather Shoes**.
>   New leather shoes can be very painful, causing blisters and other foot-related problems. Unless you soften them, they will stay that way. Fortunately, there are several was to soften the leather, making it more comfortable for your feet. ...
>   [Wikihow](https://m.wikihow.com/Soften-Leather-Shoes)

Note: *softening* is not restricted to breaking in boots or baseball gloves by wearing them.  It can instead refer to using oils or rubbing alcohol.

Answer (score 3):

There are several meanings of "broken in", some of which are related to each other:

- "The thief had *broken in* through the window" refers to the crime of "breaking and entering"; when for the purpose of intending to commit a further crime, this is covered by a separate offence of **burglary** under English law.  The thief would be called a **burglar**, and we could say that he **burgled** the house.
- "The porter *broke into* the conversation to point out that their train had arrived."  Here the meaning is **interrupted**.  The term *break in*, with this meaning, is commonly used among radio operators, eg. on board aircraft.
- "The horse had to be *broken in* before it could be ridden."  Here we could instead say **tamed** or **trained**, though that's not what a professional rider would say; they're still appropriate words for a layman character to use.
- "I wore my new boots for a week, to ensure they were *broken in*, before I climbed the mountain."  For this, **worn in** is two letters and a syllable shorter; I could also recommend **conditioned** as a single word.  It's also possible to use **softened** in this context.  A similar procedure applied to a new car would be **run in**.

Comment: I'm not sure why you included the first 3 bullet points, given that the original question specifically talks about the last meaning. It might be useful information to some, but it is a bit extraneous to the question.

Answer (score 3):

A commonly used word to imply `broken-in (baseball gloves) meaning they are ready for comfortable use` is ***preconditioned***.

ODO:

> **[preconditioned](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/preconditioned)**   ADJECTIVE
>
> **2** Brought into the desired state for use.
>
> ‘preconditioned paper’

Real-life examples:

> The following are results from [Google search for "preconditioned
>   gloves"](https://www.google.com/search?q="preconditioned+gloves"):
>
> From https://goderichminorbaseball.ca/Pages/1056/Coach_s_Corner/:
>   Preconditioned gloves mould around a hand much quicker and are quite
>   comfortable for a young player.
>
> From
>   https://epdf.tips/the-little-league-guide-to-tee-ball-helping-beginning-players-develop-coordinati.html:
>   Some glove manufacturers will offer preconditioned gloves, gloves that
>   have been treated and mechanically broken in.

Comment: Really the correct word for the OP's context is **conditioned**.  "Preconditioned" means specifically that the product was conditioned *before* it was sold, so that the purchaser doesn't need to do so himself.

Answer (score 0):

Well-tempered. Giving a connotation of 'just right'.

Comment: Well-tempered is usually used for musical instruments. It might be a little misleading when used for an item of clothing.

Comment: I disagree with @Mitch, as a non-musician, I had no idea it had that connotation.

Comment: @AzorAhai Which connotation did you have no idea about, the musical one or the broken-in one? I didn't know it had the latter (and strongly believe it does not).

Comment: @Mitch "well-tempered" meaning a musical instrument would never occur to me - I would be more likely to think of metal or chocolate.

Comment: @AzorAhai Well-tempered with metal or chocolate doesn't have the meaning of broken-in, though...

Comment: "Is there a simpler, shorter word that would convey the same message?" Does this seem shorter than "broken in"?

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach I didn't say it did. I said "well-tempered" would make me think of metal or chocolate before musical instruments.

Comment: @AzorAhai The term “well-tempered” [has exactly one meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_temperament), and it’s in the context of music. Outside of that context, “well tempered” (no dash!) simply refers to tempering (of chocolate or metal). And, contrary to what this answer suggests, “well-tempered” does *not* mean “well tempered”, nor do either mean the same as “worn in”. Furthermore, I don’t think the term “well tempered” makes a lot of sense: tempering is essentially an on/off quality, there’s *generally* not much room for doing it more or less well (with caveats).

Comment: (Correction/addition: of course “well tempered” *as well as* “well-tempered” could also refer to a person’s temperament, and that meaning is related to the musical one.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph 1) As a copy editor, there are many contexts in which I would have hyphenated "well-tempered" even if it wasn't in a musical context. 2) I don't think it's a good or an accurate answer, either. 3) I don't know anything about materials science, but I imagine it would be possibly to poorly temper something.

Comment: @AzorAhai My point is, you don’t need to be familiar with classical music to associate “well-tempered” foremost with either a person or music, given that this is its primary established meaning. I’m not categorically disputing the existence of mentions of well-tempered chocolate chocolate or steel but I maintain that these will be in a distant third place.

Comment: @KonradRudolph And I'm disagreeing with you. As someone who had never heard of that connotation, I wouldn't feel misled as Mitch suggested. Maybe everyone who took music in fourth grade would. Just providing a little bit of feedback on his comment. Either way, I think we all agree this isn't a terribly well-suited phrase.

Comment: @AzorAhai Of course you're right. Now I want chocolate

Answer (score 0):

Acclimated?  If a thing or item is acclimated it has been used enough to exist in comfort in it's environment, yes?